# Simple SQL Queries used in Ecommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, subquery

There are two tables:
Purchase_Summary containing
orderid,
orderdate,
userid

Purchase_Details containing
itemid,
orderid,
category [this field contains the name of the category like “Books”,”Music”, to which itemid belongs]
ItemPayment [this field contains the payment made for that particular itemid]

The column names are self explanatory.
An orderid can have several itemids.

Question1:
As an output we need a list of all orderids and their payments [remember the payment of an orderid will be sum of payment of all the itemids in that orderid]

Question2:
As an output we need a list of all userid and the total payment received from them in the year 2013.

Question3:
We need a list of all userids which have bought for more than 10,000 Rs. of value in 2012 but not bought at all in 2013.

Question4:
As an output we need a list of all users who have in the year 2013, bought from category called le“Books” but not bought from category called “Music”.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and SQLServer for this? Looks like a nice exercise, what have you tried so far that wasn't working? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I am using MySQL.I was able to solve first two queries bu not the last 2.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry check if it is correct?

Comment: @NickyvV check if it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the my solution.I am getting right results from below queries but if there is still ways  to optimize the solution kindly suggest me.

Ans1.

```
select orderid, sum(itempayment)
from purchase_detail
group by orderid;
```

Ans2.

```
select a.userid, sum(b.itempayment) as totalpayment
from purchase_summary as a
left join purchase_detail as b
on a.orderid = b.orderid
where year(orderdate) = '2013'
group by userid;
```

Ans 3.

```
select userid
from purchase_summary as a
inner join purchase_detail as b
on a.orderid = b.orderid
where year(orderdate) = '2012'
and userid not in
(select userid
from purchase_summary
where year(orderdate) = '2013')
group by userid
having sum(itempayment) > 10000;
```

Ans4.

```
select userid
from purchase_summary as a
inner join purchase_detail as b
on a.orderid = b.orderid
where year(orderdate) = '2013'   
and category = 'Book'
and userid not in
( select userid
from purchase_summary as a
inner join purchase_detail as b
on a.orderid = b.orderid
where year(orderdate) = '2013'
and category = 'Music'
);
```